# Show that the lines containing $n(s)$ and passing through $\alpha(s)$ meet the $z$ axis under a constant angle equal to $\pi/2$.

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

$$\alpha(s)=\left(a \cos\frac{s}{c}, a \sin\frac{s}{c}, b\frac{s}{c}\right), \quad s \in \mathbb R$$

$$n(s)=\left(\cos\frac{s}{c}, \sin\frac{s}{c}, 0\right)$$

> Show that the lines containing $n(s)$ and passing through $\alpha(s)$ meet the $z$ axis under a constant angle equal to $\pi/2$.

The line containing $n(s)$ and passing through $\alpha(s)$ is
$$\alpha(s)+tn(s)$$
but I am not getting that this is orthogonal to the $z$ axis represented by the vector $(0,0,1)$.

Any help?

Comment: What does it mean to say a *line* is perpendicular to another line?

Comment: dot product is zero

Comment: Dot product of *what* vectors? Think carefully, and draw pictures.

Comment: dot product of any vector lying on one line and any vector lying on the other lying. Then angle between any two vectors, each lying on separate lines, should not change.

Comment: What does "vector lying on [a] line" mean?

Comment: If we have a line (a linear subspace), a vector lies on a line if it points in the direction of the line.

Comment: If the line is affine, then a vector lies on the line if is it parallel to the affine line.

Comment: So you need to look at the vector $n(s)$, not the vector $\alpha(s)+tn(s)$.

Comment: Is it because the line that contains the vector $n(s)$ always passes through $\alpha(s)$?

Comment: It's because $n(s)$ is the direction vector of the line. This is the vector that needs to be perpendicular to the $z$-axis.